# how can you configure tortoisehg to see in the web servers page the "graph" link?

Tags: mercurial, webserver, dvcs, tortoisehg

In the mercurial repo i can see it.
I think that mercurial already have this feature with the revision graph.

How i've to configure tortoisehg to achieve that?

I want to have something like [this](http://selenic.com/repo/index.cgi/hg-stable/graph/b965605dfb2e) for the hgweb.

Answer (score 2):

Tortisehg doesn't have a built-in graph viewer, but it will call off to 'hg view' or 'hgk' if they're installed and you have your tortoisehg.view configured in your Mercurial.ini file.

From http://tortoisehg.wiki.sourceforge.net/FAQ:

Q: How can I add hgk (hg view) back to TortoiseHg-0.3?

A: Download tclkit and place it in your TortoiseHg directory. Download the hgk script from the Mercurial repository and place it in your TortoiseHg\contrib directory. Create an hgk.cmd file and place it in TortoiseHg\scripts. This file should contain:

```
@set HG=C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe
@"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\tclkit-win32.exe" "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\contrib\hgk" %*
```

Then enable hgk in your Mercurial.ini file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.hgk =

[hgk]
path=C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\scripts\hgk.cmd
vdiff=vdiff
```

Then tell TortoiseHg to use hgk as your external log viewer in your Mercurial.ini file. This will enable the 'Revision Graph' entry in the context menu and
cause it to launch hgk. The 'View Changelog' menu entry will still launch TortoiseHg's changelog viewer.

```
[tortoisehg]
view = hgk
```

Comment: These days TortoiseHg has a built-in history graph viewer, no configuration necessary :-)